# Safely perform TCP traceroute from user request

Tags: networking, php, tcp

I need to perform a TCP traceroute using either the Linux traceroute or another package, but I'm struggling to find a way of making the request from PHP without needing sudo privileges.

Because the URL will be from a user request I don't want to use sudo.

Here's an example:

```
 $url = 'ebay.com';
 $exec = 'sudo traceroute -w 1 -q 1 -T ' . $url;
 $escaped_command = escapeshellcmd($exec);
 $result = shell_exec($escaped_command);

 echo $result;
 var_dump($result);
```

This code works, but only with `sudo` or without `-T`. Without `sudo`, it returns an empty string. Without `-T` the traceroute does not survive firewalls.

If it helps, I'm on a Centos 7 OS.

Note: I can't use UDP instead of TCP because it often gets blocked by the destination firewall.

Comment: A few considerations when using escapeshellcmd() https://gist.github.com/Zenexer/40d02da5e07f151adeaeeaa11af9ab36

Comment: @schroeder: `-T` is short for `-M tcp` and this method is documented as using half-open connections by default and thus needs root. It is not written explicit in the man page but there is nothing written about needed permissions at all. Probably with the (explicitly not recommended) option `tcpconn` it will not need root since then it is doing a simple `connect`.

Comment: Thanks Steffen, so in that case probably with UDP and increasing the TTL can be done, however the sender needs to read the ICMP generated by the routers, so in this case I think the source application needs root permisions for read the ICMP Unreach generated, I think

Comment: @camp0 the OP says it works without sudo and without `-T`

Comment: I think @SteffenUllrich has the ultimate answer, and this is far more of a Linux question than a security question.

Comment: Thanks for the replys. It looks like it's not possible to run a TCP traceroute without sudo. The command ` $exec = 'traceroute -w 1 -q 1  ' . $url;` works fine without sudo (using UDP), so it's that or nothing I guess...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot run sudo from PHP, since Apache will not let you do that for security reasons.
You need to implement traceroute in PHP inside your code.

There are several such implementations to be found in the public domain.

See for example:

[Creating a traceroute program in PHP](https://adayinthelifeof.nl/2010/07/30/creating-a-traceroute-program-in-php/),
code is available [on github](http://github.com/jaytaph/traceroute).

---

Another approach to avoid sudo for traceroute based on the fact that
traceroute needs not run as root; it just needs the capability `CAP_NET_ADMIN`. To set this as file capability for all users,
if your kernel supports file capabilities and no Linux Security Module (SELinux, AppArmor) is blocking it:

```
setcap CAP_NET_ADMIN+ep /usr/sbin/traceroute
```

(the poster indicated it worked with `sudo setcap cap_net_raw+ep /usr/bin/traceroute`.)

The PHP code can then be very simple using `popen()`:

```
$handle = popen("traceroute www.xxx.com 2>&1", "r");
while(!feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = fgets($handle);
    $buffer = "<p>".$buffer."</p>\n";
    echo $buffer;
}
pclose($handle);
```

Comment: I'm using Nginx, so I can run sudo, but it's not safe. The PHP implementation you linked also requires sudo and uses UDP not TCP which is what I need. .

Comment: As an Nginx person, perhaps you can explain to me why sudo is necessary for sending messages on sockets.

Comment: According to a SO thread I found *Opening a raw socket allows to read anything that is received in a given interface, so, basically, you can read any packet that is directed to any application - even if that application is owned by another user. That basically means that the user with this capability is able to read any and all communications of all users.*. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404860/raw-sockets-need-root-priviliege

Comment: Right, so I added another approach.

Comment: That did it! Thanks. Strangely, I didn't need `cap_net_admin` it worked with only`cap_net_raw` like `sudo setcap cap_net_raw+ep /usr/bin/traceroute`. If I run `getcap /usr/bin/traceroute` I get `/usr/bin/traceroute = cap_net_raw+ep`. I have selinux in permissive mode at the moment, so once I enable it I guess I'll have issues to fix.